# Временные файлы в ST3

Tags: sublime-text-3

Пишу на Rust в Sublime Text 3.

Вопрос: как убрать эти временные файлы, которые засоряют иерархию? [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

С каждым разом их всё больше. Я новичок в ST3 и этот редактор мне нравится, но вот эти временные файлы не нравятся.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Открыть настройки: Preferences → Settings → User
Добавить строчку с фильтром файлов:

```
"file_exclude_patterns": ["tmp*"]
```

Либо, для директории `src`:

```
"file_exclude_patterns": ["src/tmp*"]
```

Comment: а как-то вообще отключить никак?

Comment: для этого надо знать, откуда они у вас берутся

Comment: похоже это что-то связанное с Rust. Появилось, когда установил плагины для него, если не ошибаюсь. 
Установленные плагины: 
— AdvancedNewFile;
— AutoFileName;
— Rust;
— RustAutoComplete;
— RustCodeFormatter;
— SideBarEnhancements. 
Возможно один из них это делает.